# scipy stats.ttest_rel(): how to change confidence level to 99%

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, confidence-interval

I think the default confidence level is 95% and just curious if it can be changed to 99%. Thanks!

```
from scipy import stats
np.random.seed(12345678) # fix random seed to get same numbers
rvs1 = stats.norm.rvs(loc=5,scale=10,size=500)
rvs2 = (stats.norm.rvs(loc=5,scale=10,size=500) + stats.norm.rvs(scale=0.2,size=500))
stats.ttest_rel(rvs1,rvs2)
```

Comment: `ttest_rel` *returns* the p-value. It doesn't accept a confidence interval or have any notion of one.

Comment: Is there another way to do t-test in python and set the confidence level to 95%? Thanks @jme

Comment: I think you misunderstand. `ttest_rel` returns the p-value. Just compare the p-value to 95% or whatever you'd like.